# how to draw multiple serial curve lines with the same animation speed using echarts

Tags: javascript, echarts

I was using [echarts](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-lines.polyline) to draw curve lines in the map. For example, https://gallery.echartsjs.com/editor.html?c=xDYyde55iN&v=3
I was hoping to draw the lines with `lineStyle.curveness`.
However, as you can see in the demo,
the `polyline: false` doesn't work with `data.coords` more than 2, the last item in the `data.coords` was ignored.
If using with  `polyline: true`, the `curveness` would fail.

So I was hoping something like this https://gallery.echartsjs.com/editor.html?c=xXrcAUdpxw
I achieve this by delaying the last line animation. However, if using this,  I can't **keep the same animation speed** between lines.

So, I was seeking if there is a way to **keep the same animation speed** between lines based on this demo  https://gallery.echartsjs.com/editor.html?c=xXrcAUdpxw.

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding of the problem, I tried to figure it out by taking actual cases based on this following demo https://gallery.echartsjs.com/editor.html?c=xXrcAUdpxw.

In the demo, there are two path, each consist of two lines. In summary, we can achieve the same animation speed by calculating how long the arrow took to move along the path.

From now let's take a constant speed of 100 km/s for each arrow.

The first step is calculate each distance between two points in the path:

Path 1:

- Distance between ["121.207619", "31.237319"] and ["114.48229029384036", "36.76552732148951"] is 872 km. Travel time: (872 km) / (100 km/s) = 8.72 s
- Distance between ["114.48229029384036", "36.76552732148951"] and ["116.119589", "38.113789"] is 208 km. Travel time: 2.08 s

Path 2:

- Distance between ["121.207619", "31.237319"] and ["116.06354284749577", "39.49194673976087"] is 1028 km. Travel time: 10.28 s
- Distance between ["116.06354284749577", "39.49194673976087"] and ["116.119589", "38.113789"] is 153 km. Travel time: 1.53 s

You can use already available library to calculate distance between two coordinates.

Now, we can use these information to set animation duration in the chart options. For example, for Path 1:

- Line 1:

Set `animationDuration` to travel time the arrow took to move along line 1, i.e. 8720 (miliseconds), and `effect.period` to 8.72 (seconds). Then, set `animationDelay` and `effect.delay` to 0 as it start immediately. We also set `animationThreshold` large enough so that ECharts wouldn't ignore the animation. See example below:

```
{
  type: "lines",
  coordinateSystem: "bmap",
  zlevel: 1,
  lineStyle: {
    normal: {
      color: "#ff0000",
      width: 2,
      opacity: 0.3,
      curveness: 0.2,
    },
  },
  animationThreshold: 100000,
  animationDuration: 8720,
  animationEasing: "linear",
  effect: {
    show: true,
    trailLength: 0,
    symbol: "arrow",
    symbolSize: 10,
    loop: false,
    period: 8.72,
    delay: 0,
  },
  animationDelay: 0,
  data: [
    {
      fromName: "上海",
      toName: "邢邯",
      coords: [
        ["121.207619", "31.237319"],
        ["114.48229029384036", "36.76552732148951"],
      ],
    },
  ],
},
```

- Line 2:

In line 2, set `animationDuration` to travel time the arrow took to move along line 2, i.e. 2080 (miliseconds) and set `effect.period` to 2.08 (seconds). Set `effect.delay` and `animationDelay` to 8720 (miliseconds) because it start when line 1 animation had done. See example below:

```
{
  type: "lines",
  coordinateSystem: "bmap",
  zlevel: 1,
  lineStyle: {
    normal: {
      color: "#ff0000",
      width: 2,
      opacity: 0.3,
      curveness: 0.2,
    },
  },
  animationThreshold: 100000,
  animationDuration: 2080,
  animationEasing: "linear",
  symbol: ["none", "arrow"],
  symbolSize: 10,
  effect: {
    show: true,
    trailLength: 0,
    symbol: "arrow",
    symbolSize: 10,
    loop: false,
    period: 2.08,
    delay: 8720,
  },
  animationDelay: 8720,
  data: [
    {
      fromName: "邢邯",
      toName: "沧衡",
      coords: [
        ["114.48229029384036", "36.76552732148951"],
        ["116.119589", "38.113789"],
      ],
    },
  ],
},
```

Finally use the same method for line 3, and line 4 in the Path 2.

Complete example:

```
var series = [
  {
    type: "lines",
    coordinateSystem: "bmap",
    zlevel: 1,
    lineStyle: {
      normal: {
        color: "#ff0000",
        width: 2,
        opacity: 0.3,
        curveness: 0.2,
      },
    },
    animationThreshold: 100000,
    animationDuration: 8720,
    animationEasing: "linear",
    effect: {
      show: true,
      trailLength: 0,
      symbol: "arrow",
      symbolSize: 10,
      loop: false,
      period: 8.72,
      delay: 0,
    },
    animationDelay: 0,
    data: [
      {
        fromName: "上海",
        toName: "邢邯",
        coords: [
          ["121.207619", "31.237319"],
          ["114.48229029384036", "36.76552732148951"],
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    type: "lines",
    coordinateSystem: "bmap",
    zlevel: 1,
    lineStyle: {
      normal: {
        color: "#ff0000",
        width: 2,
        opacity: 0.3,
        curveness: 0.2,
      },
    },
    animationThreshold: 100000,
    animationDuration: 2080,
    animationEasing: "linear",
    symbol: ["none", "arrow"],
    symbolSize: 10,
    effect: {
      show: true,
      trailLength: 0,
      symbol: "arrow",
      symbolSize: 10,
      loop: false,
      period: 2.08,
      delay: 8720,
    },
    animationDelay: 8720,
    data: [
      {
        fromName: "邢邯",
        toName: "沧衡",
        coords: [
          ["114.48229029384036", "36.76552732148951"],
          ["116.119589", "38.113789"],
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    type: "lines",
    coordinateSystem: "bmap",
    zlevel: 1,
    lineStyle: {
      normal: {
        color: "#ff0000",
        width: 2,
        opacity: 0.3,
        curveness: 0.2,
      },
    },
    animationThreshold: 100000,
    animationDuration: 10280,
    animationEasing: "linear",
    effect: {
      show: true,
      trailLength: 0,
      symbol: "arrow",
      symbolSize: 10,
      loop: false,
      period: 10.28,
      delay: 0,
    },
    animationDelay: 0,
    data: [
      {
        fromName: "上海",
        toName: "京南",
        coords: [
          ["121.207619", "31.237319"],
          ["116.06354284749577", "39.49194673976087"],
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    type: "lines",
    coordinateSystem: "bmap",
    zlevel: 1,
    lineStyle: {
      normal: {
        color: "#ff0000",
        width: 2,
        opacity: 0.3,
        curveness: 0.2,
      },
    },
    animationThreshold: 100000,
    animationDuration: 1530,
    animationEasing: "linear",
    symbol: ["none", "arrow"],
    symbolSize: 10,
    effect: {
      show: true,
      trailLength: 0,
      symbol: "arrow",
      symbolSize: 10,
      loop: false,
      period: 1.53,
      delay: 10280,
    },
    animationDelay: 10280,
    data: [
      {
        fromName: "京南",
        toName: "沧衡",
        coords: [
          ["116.06354284749577", "39.49194673976087"],
          ["116.119589", "38.113789"],
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];

option = {
  bmap: {
    zoom: 6,
    roam: true,
  },
  animation: false,
  series,
};
```